# как сделать нейронную простейшую сеть с 1 входом и 1 выходом

Tags: c#, c++, нейронные-сети

Мне надо научить сеть делать что-то типо мат функций.Т.е обучить её к примеру умножения на 5:
1--5
2--10
3--15
4--20
в интернете все примеры про картинки и т.д.Ничего похожего не нашел.

Comment: Вы умножаете только целые числа или дробные тоже?

Comment: @kir_antipov мне бы хотя бы для целых понять.

Comment: просто модели в таком случае разные будут) Вас интересует сама модель нейронной сети или ещё и как ее построить самостоятельно? Я просто могу по-быстрому привести пример с использованием готовой библиотеки для построения нейронных сетей на .Net-языках (таких как С#)

Comment: @kir_antipov мне надо просто для проверки результатов нейросолюшина.Есть 2 ряда цифр.Один ряд - входные,2 ряд - выходные.Вот мне надо реализовать проверку на с++ или шарпе